# Passport.js multiple strategies for a single route. Use sessions for only one strategy

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, session, passport.js

I am building an API endpoint with `Express`, `NodeJS`, `PassportJS`, and `TypeScript`. I want to allow two types of authentication for this endpoint. SAML (for humans) and token for automation. For human authentication, I'm using the `passport-saml` strategy. For token auth I'm using `passport-http` basic authentication. So far my code looks like:

```js
import session from "express-session";

const samlStrategy = getSamlStrategy();
const basicStrategy = getBasicStrategy();

app.use((req, res, next) =>
  session({
    // store sessions in db
  })(req, res, next)
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  //...
});

passport.deserializeUser((username, done) => {
  //...
});

passport.use(samlStrategy);
passport.use(basicStrategy);

const requireApiAuth: express.Handler = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401);
  }
};

const tryTokenAuth: express.Handler = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.user && req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.indexOf("Basic") > -1) {
    passport.authenticate("basic", { session: false })(req, res, next);
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

//...
// SAML endpoints here
//...

app.use(
  "/api",
  tryServiceUserAuth,
  requireApiAuth,
```

The basic idea is the middleware function `tryTokenAuth` will check to see if a `user` is already present on the request. If there is, then that means a human has already logged in via SAML auth. If there is no `user` AND if the request specifies Basic authorization then we should use the `basic` strategy to authenticate. At the moment, this is working. I am able to authenticate using either strategy for the `/api` route.

The issue is that even though I specify `{session: false}` for `basic` authentication I'm STILL getting a session cookie sent back in the response. And a session is being recorded in my database. I don't understand what I need to configure to prevent this behavior. I do NOT want a session to be created when `basic` auth is used.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out specifying `session: false` in the call to authenticate only prevents `passport` from adding its session data to a request session. The reason a session is still being created is because my config says:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) =>
  session({
    // store sessions in db
  })(req, res, next)
);
```

In order to prevent this when using basic auth I had to update to:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.indexOf("Basic") > -1) {
    next();
  } else {
    session({
      // store sessions in db
    })(req, res, next)
  }
});
```